# Run Integration test in toplevel pom

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

I have a project with 3 modules.I used maven as the build tool.I have Integration test module

```
Proj/mod1/pom.xml
Proj/mod2/pom.xml
Proj/intTest/pom.xml
Proj/pom.xml
```

Now I want to run the integration test using top level pom.xml,Is there a way to do that??

Thanxxx

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I get it right the *intTest*-project does your integration tests and is part of your project *Proj* so if you run the module build with the appropriate phase (integration-test or verify, depending on what you use) this should be it ...